# Rotating a 5D array in the last 2 dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rotation, vectorization

I have a 5D array 'a', of size (3,2,2,2,2).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(48).reshape(3,2,2,2,2)
a[0,0,0]:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

What I want to do is rotate this 5D array by 180 degrees, but only in the last two dimensions, without their positions changed. So output[0,0,0] should look like this:

```
out[0,0,0]:
array([[3, 2],
       [1, 0]])
```

What I have tried:

```
out = np.rot90(a, 2)
out[0,0,0]:
array([[40, 41],
       [42, 43]])
```

The `rot90` function apparently rotates the whole array.

Note: I want to avoid using for loops if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate the last two axes 180 degrees, pass `axes=(-2, -1)` to `np.rot90`:

```
>>> a180 = np.rot90(a, 2, axes=(-2, -1))
>>> a180[0, 0, 0]
array([[3, 2],
       [1, 0]])
```

If your version of NumPy does not have the `axes` parameter with `np.rot90`, there are alternatives.

One way is with indexing:

```
a180 = a[..., ::-1, ::-1]
```

`rot90` flips the *first* two axes of the array, therefore to use it you'd need to transpose (to reverse the axes), rotate, and transpose back again. For example:

```
np.rot90(a.T, 2).T
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't though of that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you could *reverse* the arrangement of the elements along the last two axes, like so -

```
a[:,:,::-1,::-1]
```

You can also reshape to a 2D array merging the last two axes as the last axis, then *reverse* elements along it and reshape back, like so -

```
a.reshape(-1,np.prod(a.shape[-2:]))[:,::-1].reshape(a.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [141]: a[0][0]
Out[141]: 
array([[57, 64, 69],
       [41, 28, 89]])

In [142]: out1 = a[:,:,::-1,::-1]

In [143]: out2 = a.reshape(-1,np.prod(a.shape[-2:]))[:,::-1].reshape(a.shape)

In [144]: out1[0][0]
Out[144]: 
array([[89, 28, 41],
       [69, 64, 57]])

In [145]: out2[0][0]
Out[145]: 
array([[89, 28, 41],
       [69, 64, 57]])
```